# I am Having Issues Accessing My Custom Data In Flutter, How To Access The Features Data in The Data Below

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-test, flutter-design

Here is the JSON path need to be edited:

```
List populars = [
  {
    "image":
        "",
    "name": "Single Villa",
    "price": "280,000FCFA",
  }
    ]
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're tring to implement your code as Map.

In order to use your JSON format in Dart, you need to make it Map first.

```
Map map = populars.asMap();
```

Then you can use it like that:

```
print(map[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if you want to get the data inside your created json either ways there are more ways to it.

```
final getFeatures = populars.map((e)=> e['features']).first; 
  print(getFeatures[0]['type']);
  print(getFeatures[1]['rooms']);
  print(getFeatures[2]['toilet']);
  print(getFeatures[3]['parlor']);
  print(getFeatures[4]['water']);
 
//Result
Studio
1
1
1
true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the structure itself,
it should be like this:

```
{
"name": "Single Villa",
"features": {
  "type": "Studio",
  "rooms": 1,
  "toilet": 1,
  "parlor": 1,
  "water": true
  }
},
```

then you can use it like this:

```
final name = populars[index]['name'];
final rooms = populars[index]['features']['rooms'];
...
```